# Автоматический путь миграции Typeorm при ее генерации и создании

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Нужна помощь работе с миграциями в typeorm >= 0.3

Как сделать так что бы при создании миграции она автоматически попадала в указанный заранее путь

Пример того что я хочу

`yarn migration:genereate CreateUserEntity`

В результате должна создаться миграции в ./src/migrations

В версии 0.2 можно было это указать в cli: {} при создании соединения

На данный момент необходимо прописывать путь до директории с миграциями целиком

`yarn migration:genereate ./src/migrationsCreateUserEntity`

скриты в package.json

```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/data-source.ts",
"migration:generate": "yarn typeorm -- migration:generate",
"migration:run": "yarn typeorm -- migration:run",
```

data-sorce.ts

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  database: 'xxx_db',
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'admin',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*.{ts,js}'],
  migrationsTableName: 'migrate',
};

const AppDataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);

export default AppDataSource;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100356/4496422

Comment: Unknown argument: name